# dbms related to cloud storage like google drive

Tags: php, mysql, database, google-cloud-storage, dropbox

My project is similar to google drive. My question is when one user upload any file like video, mp3, .txt then I have to store the path of that file in an database under that particular username. But if one have 20gb drive limit then he can upload 10000 files of size 1kb very easily then in that case how to store every file path in database? Or it can be done in some other way?

Comment: What's the problem with storing them all in the database? If you want to implement a limit on the number of files a user can upload, that's a separate question.

Comment: no in case of online drive i can upload as many files as i want .So i thought the database for those file would go very higher in size.Thats why i wanted to know if there exist any more efficient way to store this file related information

Comment: ok got the solution ;) thanx